Json data is not reaching to the controller
i am trying to send this json data to my controller but its not going can you please check it out for me? thanks in advance
// this is my script in form file

function verifyTransactionOnBackend(transactionId) { // console.log("Verifying transaction on backend, transaction ID:", transactionId);
    const postData = {
        transaction_id: transactionId,
        store_id: document.getElementById("store_id").value,
        plan_id: document.getElementById("plan_id").value,
        start_date: document.getElementById("start_date").value,
        end_date: document.getElementById("end_date").value,
        status: 'active',
        price: document.getElementById("price").value,
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('membership/insert_user_payment')?>",
        data: postData, // No need to stringify if contentType is not set to "application/json"
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Server response:", response);
            if (response.status && response.status === 'success') {
                window.location.href = "<?php echo admin_url('welcome'); ?>";
            } else {
                console.error("Error in response:", response.msg || "Undefined error message");
                document.querySelector("#payment-failed").style.display = 'block';
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            document.querySelector("#payment-failed").style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}

// this is my controller 
public function insert_user_payment() {    
    $postData = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream, true);
    
    // Prepare the data for insertion
    $insert_data = [
        'transaction_id' => $postData['transaction_id'],
        'tore_id' => $postData['store_id'],
        'plan_id' => $postData['plan_id'],
        'tart_date' => $postData['start_date'],
        'end_date' => $postData['end_date'],
        'tatus' => $postData['status'],
        'price' => $postData['price']
    ];

    var_dump($postData);
    
    $insert = $this->db->insert('membership_payments', $insert_data);
    
    // Check if the insert was successful
    if ($insert) {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'uccess', 'sg' => 'Payment recorded successfully.']);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'sg' => 'Failed to record payment.']);
    }
}


What makes you think you were sending JSON there? You aren't. You are passing an object for data (and did not set processData to false), so this will generate an application/x-www-form-urlencoded request.

'status' => 'uccess' in your response is a typo, response.status === 'success' will never trigger

Read https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - "When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to false. For example, { a: "bc", d: "e,f" } is converted to the string "a=bc&d=e%2Cf" ". This is a jquery issue, nothing to do with your PHP code

@CBroe true, but simply setting processData to false and then passing in a JS object to data will result in the string [object Object] being sent to the server, which is no use. contentType: "application/json" needs to be set, and data: JSON.stringify(postData) needs to be used.

@ADyson I wasn't suggesting that setting processData: false would fix the issue, I just quoted that part for completeness sake. "contentType: "application/json" needs to be set, and data: JSON.stringify(postData) needs to be used." - not sure why this should be send as JSON in the first place. Nothing wrong with application/x-www-form-urlencoded per se.

@CBroe of course there isn't, but if it wants to match with how the PHP is currently written then it would be needed.
